solr upgraded from 8.11.1 to solr 9.5.0 and having one core issue
we have upgraded solr 8.11.1 to solr 9.5.0 and all core copied and working as excpected nut one collection its not working giving "Stream Body is disabled." error.
for this i have added this snip in core conf solrconfig.xml but no luck. i have also tried this through postman but no luck its giving the same error.
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                enableStreamBody="true"
                multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>

i have also tried on solr.cmd (solr start file) added this condition. not working as expected.

# Remote streaming and stream body
if [ "${SOLR_ENABLE_REMOTE_STREAMING:-false}" == "true" ]; then
  SCRIPT_SOLR_OPTS+=("-Dsolr.enableRemoteStreaming=true")
fi
if [ "${SOLR_ENABLE_STREAM_BODY:-false}" == "true" ]; then
  SCRIPT_SOLR_OPTS+=("-Dsolr.enableStreamBody=true")
fi

i have added through JAVA code added headers code snip but getting same error
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(solrApiUrl + endpoint);

httpGet.addHeader("requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableRemoteStreaming","true");
httpGet.addHeader("requestDispatcher.requestParsers.enableStreamBody","true");

when i am trying same code in lower version of solr then its working as expected.

Basically i am getting error bad request(400) but same code and same data is working on 8.11.1 and 9.1.0 and 9.2.0 as expected.

This is the error i am getting when i am hitting delete query through code
"Stream Body is disabled"
